# Optimizing wallpapers for eye strain?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I noticed a lot of wallpapers are really hard on the eyes after awhile, what can I do to keep the colors vibrant but optimized to reduce eye strain?

For example,

This is a pretty balanced wallpaper: [image]

Example of an unbalanced one: [image]

Comment: I think you have the idea, keep contrast down to keep it easy on the eyes. There are guidelines for readability and color combinations that are easy to see, but I haven't heard of any for soothing palettes. Some software comes with light or dark settings, so either light text on dark background or dark text on light background, and many in between. If people can stare at these extreme contrasts for hours on end then maybe our eyes can take the strain. For your background to not intrude or interfere with the windows above then make it midtones, like in your example above. IDK Y u got down votes

Comment: Or you could just [do what I do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykq8I.png)....

Comment: @Cai xD Haha I guess that's true. It's an overall thing I've been wanting to learn though because it could be important for pretty much all design. A few things I noticed so far are light tones, off white, or gray is usually the easiest on the eyes unless the image is viewed in bright sunlight. Masking with the z depth of the image, blurring the bg very slightly, and improving the contrast have helped so far. I haven't found a fast filter or something like that to quickly fix any image though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try blending the background with gausian blur to reduce the intensity and eye strain. Another solution is to decrease the saturation. It will make your eye focus on the subject rather than the background.